# Sync multiple server configs

Tags: linux, centos, synchronization

I have a pool of servers and keeping them the same has been a challenge. I'm running the latest CentOS 6 and I'd like them to all have the same server configurations (updates and installed modules). I don't need my files sync as I use rsync for that.

Currently I have to log into each of them and do updates and installs manually.

Thanks

Comment: A configuration management tool will be your friend.

Comment: Recommendations?

Comment: I would look at salt. A new comer, but with lots of development. It's engineered to be a lot easier than CFEngine and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Configuration Management

There are plenty of software tools that handle configuration management for you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management

> Configuration management can be used to maintain OS configuration
>   files.[11] Example systems include CFEngine, Bcfg2, Puppet, and Chef.

### SSH

You have plenty of options, for example if you simply want to ssh into multiple servers and execute commands you could use something like Fabric

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/

> Fabric is a Python (2.5 or higher) library and command-line tool for
>   streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems
>   administration tasks.
>
> It provides a basic suite of operations for executing local or remote
>   shell commands (normally or via sudo) and uploading/downloading files,
>   as well as auxiliary functionality such as prompting the running user
>   for input, or aborting execution.